# Poisson Integral Formula

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

I'm looking at the following problem.

> Prove that if $h$ is harmonic on an open neighborhood of the disc
>   $B(w,\rho)$, then for $0 \leq r < \rho, 0 \leq t < 2\pi$, $$h
>  \left(w+r\mathrm{e}^{it} \right) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\rho^2 - r^2}{\rho^2 - 2\rho r \cos(\theta - t) + r^2} h\left(w
>  + \rho\mathrm{e}^{i\theta} \right) \, \mathrm{d}\theta.$$

We know that the Poisson integral of a continuous function $\phi: \partial B \to \mathbb{R}$ where $D=U(w,\rho)$, $w \in \mathbb{C}, \rho > 0$ has the exact form $$P_D \phi \left( w + r \mathrm{e}^{it} \right)
 = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\rho^2 - r^2}{\rho^2 - 2\rho r \cos(\theta - t) + r^2} \phi \left(w
 + \rho\mathrm{e}^{i\theta} \right) \, \mathrm{d}\theta$$ for $0 \leq r < \rho, 0 \leq t < 2\pi$. To solve the problem, is it as simple as saying that the function $h$ is itself continuous on the boundary and so $h$ will act as $\phi$ in the Poisson integral?

Hope you can help!

Comment: Which properties of $P_D\phi$ are known?

Comment: Hmm, nothing more is stated in the problem. But we know that for $D=U(w,\rho)$ and $\phi = \partial B(w,\rho) \to \mathbb{R}$ (where $U$ is open disk and $B$ closed disk) the solution to the Dirichlet problem is given by the function $g= P_D\phi$ in $U(w,\rho)$ and $g=\phi$ in $\partial B(w,\rho)$. Was this what you were thinking of?

Comment: And it is harmonic.

Comment: I guess "solution to the Dirichlet problem" includes the continuity at the boundary. So you know that $h - P_Dh$ is a harmonic function with boundary values $0$.

Comment: Hence $h=P_D h$ on the boundary and therefore $h=P_D h$ in the interior by the definition of the solution of the Dirichlet problem on the open ball?

Comment: What do you know about the solution of the Dirichlet problem? Does that allow you the (true) conclusion that $h = P_Dh$?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11987/discussion-between-bo-schmidt-and-daniel-fischer)